# What Security Issues I should have in PHP Hosting

Tags: php, security, hosting

Just wanted to know what could be the security cautions I should know about PHP Hosting?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some of the things:

- Disable functions like `eval`, `passthru`, `shell_exec`,etc
- Remote url injection, disable `allow_url_fopen`
- Disable `register_globals`

And don't forget:

- You are responsible too. Write secure code, read security tutorials out there.

**[PHP Security Guide](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/)**

Finally as suggested by Rook, you should run:

**PHPSecInfo** script to see security settings of your host.

http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/

**For webhosts and Development Teams**

In development environments make sure you have appropriate coding standards. If you feel you are hosting insecure code which you did not write, consider installing a Web Application Firewall. Also consider steps to prevent bruteforce attacks (for example if you are hosting popular CMS tools), an Intrusion Prevention System like Fail2Ban can help you do this. A lot of these issues are covered in this talk [Practical Web Security – Junade Ali](https://northernoptic.com/2015/09/10/the-lead-developer-lightening-talk-practical-web-security-junade-ali/), the video of the talk is [here](https://vimeo.com/139608340).

For PHP you can also consider using [Suhosin](https://suhosin.org) which adds a number of security features to the PHP core. Be careful installing it first and test your sites afterwards to ensure it doesn't break anything.

Comment: Those are only useful if you are a bad developer

Comment: @kemp: When it comes to security no one is a perfect developer, everyone could try his best as per his knowledge to avoid any mishaps. And if you search on SO, even the most experienced developers have been compromised due to bad settings on the hosting which was not the fault of them (and yes they should have taken this in account too). Also hundreds of sites have been hacked due to `eval` functions being active through a php shell 99 malacious script. Finally, in my last list item, i have said, **You are responsible too**

Comment: Depends on what side the OP is on: my point is that if you are a developer you'd better not rely on server settings for your own security. If you are a hosting provider then it's another matter.

Comment: @kemp: and i agree to that too.

Comment: +1 you totally are correct,  however you should tell people to run PHPSecInfo (http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/) because there are other nasty configuration issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you speak as developer (and not as hoster), then don't rely on the server -- write secure code and you won't be harmed by any php configuration directive ever.

Comment: If that was the only case, I would not have asked this question.

Comment: see this please: http://www.topwebhostreview.net/security-cautions-for-php-hosting/

Comment: Your question can be read in different ways, this was just my take on it.

Comment: register_globals will probably make a secure application vulnerable to attack.  Here is an exploit that i have written which is an a good example: (http://milw0rm.com/exploits/7909).

Answer (score 0):

Clients often have access to Perl, PHP and shell accounts which makes it easy for a client to DoS or Denial of Service all the other clients with a badly written program.
External DoS on the whole hosting service, which means that if an IP is experiencing a DoS attack, you also suffer the same problem with the others.
Most often than not, clients of shared hosting solutions also share an IP address with other clients. This arrangement often works out fine but it is important to know that whatever happens to your neighbours sharing the same IP with you will also get to you. If your neighbour using the same IP will be placed on a spam blacklist, everybody else using the IP will also share the same fate.
It is very vulnerable to malware attacks.
Other harmful data can be uploaded in the other sites easily, putting your site at risk. These can be introduced to the server through vulnerabilities of a legitimate clients’ website and can be used steal data.
DDoS attacks launched by software loaded into the server allow hackers to control an entire hosting server and then attack other server, either from the same network or from other networks.